# My linked list method for counting occurences of object doesn't seem to be terminating. Any ideas?

Tags: java, linked-list

Hey there and thanks for taking the time to look at my code! I greatly appreciate you.
Just to give a little background I previously created a sorted array of Pokemon for an assignment. Now, the next assignment is to do all of the same things except use a linked list (without importing automatic tools, we're doing it all from scratch). As far as I can tell this just entails switching out the array based for loops for linked list while loops.
Here's the problem. My method for counting occurrences has been breaking my code for a few hours now and I've got now idea what to do. The method is supposed to take a boolean instance as a parameter and compare that to a Pokemon on my list (my boolean instance variable is waterType and then return how many Pokemon match that.
I've tried contstructing a new Pokemon inside the method with my 3 argument constructor and just filling in the boolean instance while leaving the String and int "null" and "0", but that throws an excepting at runtime Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toLowerCase()" because "temp.name" is null
at orderedListApp/orderedListApp.Pokemon.compareTo(Pokemon.java:58)
at orderedListApp/orderedListApp.PokemonLinkedList.countOccurrences(PokemonLinkedList.java:64)
at orderedListApp/orderedListApp.Driver.main(Driver.java:22)"
I then tried to create a new Pokemon inside the method that matched a Pokemon on my list exactly for all three variables and now the program won't even terminate. If I place the method before others at runtime the others never even output. If anyone has any ideas here I'd sure appreciate it! Also, forgive all of my commented out sections, those are methods that I've yet to update to linked list format (or attempt to).

```
package orderedListApp;

public class Pokemon {
    private String name;
    private int hp;
    private boolean waterType;
    public Pokemon(String name, int hp, boolean waterType) {
        this.name= name;
        this.hp = hp;
        this.waterType = waterType;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }

    public void setHp(int hp) {
        this.hp = hp;
    }

    public boolean isWaterType() {
        return waterType;
    }

    public void setWaterType(boolean waterType) {
        this.waterType = waterType;
    }

    public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
        return name.compareTo(anotherString);
    }
      @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Pokemon other = (Pokemon) obj;
            if (!this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(other.name)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
      public int compareTo(Pokemon temp) {
            return this.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(temp.name.toLowerCase());
        }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        output += name + "\t\t" + hp + "\t\t" + waterType;
        return output;
    }
    
    

}

package orderedListApp;

public class PokemonNode {
    private PokemonNode link;
    private Pokemon data;
    
    public PokemonNode(Pokemon data, PokemonNode link) {
        this.link = link;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public PokemonNode getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(PokemonNode link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Pokemon getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Pokemon data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    

}

package orderedListApp;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class PokemonLinkedList implements Iterable<Pokemon> {

    PokemonNode head;
    // variable to store size
    int manyItems;

    // constructor
    public PokemonLinkedList() {
        head = null;
        manyItems = 0;
    }

    public void insert(Pokemon poke) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new PokemonNode(poke, null);
        } else if (poke.compareTo(head.getData()) < 0) {
            head = new PokemonNode(poke, head);
        } else {
            PokemonNode previous = findPreviousNode(poke);
            previous.setLink(new PokemonNode(poke, previous.getLink()));
        }
        manyItems++;
    }

    private PokemonNode findPreviousNode(Pokemon poke) {
        PokemonNode cursor = head;
        while (cursor.getLink() != null && cursor.getData().compareTo(poke) < 0)
            ;
        {

            cursor = cursor.getLink();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // method to return total number of pokemon in the list
    public int size() {
        return this.manyItems;
    }

    public void removePokemon(Pokemon poketoRemove) {
        if (head != null && head.getData().equals(poketoRemove)) {
            head = head.getLink();
        } else if (head != null) {
            PokemonNode previous = findPreviousNodeRemove(poketoRemove);
            previous.setLink(previous.getLink().getLink());
        }
    }

    private PokemonNode findPreviousNodeRemove(Pokemon pokeToRemove) {
        PokemonNode cursor = head;
        while (cursor.getLink() != null && !cursor.getData().equals(pokeToRemove)) {
            cursor = cursor.getLink();

        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public int countOccurrences(boolean b) {
        PokemonNode cursor = head;
        int count = 0;
        Pokemon poke = new Pokemon(null, 0, true);
        while (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.getData().compareTo(poke) == 0)
                cursor = cursor.getLink();
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

//      public boolean contains(Pokemon oneThing) {
//          for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
//              if(pokemon[i].equals(oneThing))
//                  return true;
//          }
//          return false;
//      }

//      public int total() {
//          int total = 0;
//          for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
//              total += pokemon[i].getHp();
//          }
//          return total;
//      }
//      public int countRange(int low, int high) {
//          if(low>high)
//              return 0;
//          int count = 0;
//          PokemonNode cursor = head;
//          while(cursor != head) {
//              if(cursor )
//          }
//          
//          return count;
//          

//       for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
//              if(pokemon[i].getHp()>=low && pokemon[i].getHp()<=high)
//                  count++;
//          }
//          return count;
    // }
    // toString method
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = "Type" + "\t\t" + "Hp" + "\t\t" + "Water type" + "\n";
        output += "------------------------\n";

        PokemonNode cursor = head;
        while (cursor != null) {
            output += cursor.getData() + "\n";
            cursor = cursor.getLink();
        }
        return output;
    }

    private class PokemonIteratorClass implements Iterator<Pokemon> {
        int cursor = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {

            return cursor < manyItems;
        }

        @Override
        public Pokemon next() {

            return head.getData();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Pokemon> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

//      public Iterator<Pokemon> iterator() {
//          Iterator<Pokemon> it = new Iterator<Pokemon>() {
//              private int currentIndex = manyItems-1;
//              @Override
//              System.out.println("LinkedList elements:");
//              while(it.hasNext()){
//                 System.out.println(it.next());
//          };
//          return it;

//  }
//  }
}

package orderedListApp;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // PokemonOrderedList pokemon = new PokemonOrderedList(10);
        PokemonLinkedList pokemon2 = new PokemonLinkedList();
        pokemon2.insert(new Pokemon("Pikachu", 2, false));
        pokemon2.insert(new Pokemon("Gigachu", 2, true));
        // pokemon.insert(new Pokemon("Pikachu ", 2, false));
        // pokemon.insert(new Pokemon("Squirtle", 3, true));
        // pokemon.insert(new Pokemon("Geodude ", 2, false));
        // pokemon.insert(new Pokemon("Meowth ", 2, false));
        // pokemon.insert(new Pokemon("Magicarp", 1, true));

        System.out.println("Collection size: " + pokemon2.size());
        System.out.println(pokemon2);
        System.out.println("Water types: " + pokemon2.countOccurrences(true));
//              System.out.println("Find Pokemon: "+pokemon.find("Magicarp"));
//              System.out.println("Contains Geodude?: "+pokemon.contains(new Pokemon("Geodude  ", 2, false)));
//              System.out.println("Contains Onyx?: "+pokemon.contains(new Pokemon("Gremlin", 2, false)));
//              System.out.println("Total hp: "+pokemon.total());
//              System.out.println("Average hp is: " + pokemon.average());
//              System.out.println("Number of pokemon with hp between the entered range: " + pokemon.countRange(1, 30));

    }

}
```

Comment: Please step through your program with the debugger.

Comment: Much of this doesn't make sense.   `CountOccurrences()` doesn't use the `boolean` parameter at all, and `compareTo()` (but `Pokemon` doesn't implement `Comparable<Pokemon>`) and `equals()` compare based on the name (case-insensitive).  You should be stepping through the code in your debugger to figure out where it deviates from your expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys! I'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `CountOccurences()` code is rather confusing. It appears to always increase the count, regardless of the `waterType` variable, and only continues through the list if an odd condition is met. Try this instead:

```
public int countOccurrences(boolean b) {
    PokemonNode cursor = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getData().isWaterType() == b) 
            count++;
        cursor = cursor.getLink();
    }
    return count;
}
```

This will check if the `waterType` of each Pokemon is equal to the querying Boolean `b`, and if it is, add one to the count.